# How to find old papers on a particular topic?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, advice, online-resources

> When learning mathematics, I think it is better to learn the motivation and the purpose of a particular maths idea. I believe such things are best found in the original paper which proposes the idea. How could I find such papers?

For example, I am currently learning group theory. How could I find an old paper which proposed the theory?

Comment: try http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/math and in particular http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/math.HO

Comment: If you think you're going to get anything out of, say, Galois's old manuscripts then you're probably mistaken.

Comment: @mathers01: have you read Galois' work?

Comment: @janmarqz Fantastic! Are old papers included in the database? I tried search Riemann but cannot find his papers.

Comment: @Rescy_ it is hard to find everything but there are opinions, like http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0305.5022

Comment: @Rescy: the links that janmarqz gives are front ends to http://arxiv.org, which only contains recent e-prints (some of which *are* about the history of mathematics). However, an increasing number of important historical mathematical  papers are available on line. For Riemann, have a look at the references in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernhard_Riemann.

Answer (score 3):

[Harold Edwards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harold_Edwards_(mathematician)) agrees with you about reading original sources. His [book on Galois Theory](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Galois-Theory-Graduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/038790980X) includes a translation of the seminal papers on Group Theory and an excellent account of the mathematics from both the original and the modern perspective.